# Perl Dancer - still using port 3000

Tags: perl, localhost, port, dancer

I have tested Perl programming langugage for a while and installed Perl Dancer web framework. Dance server used port 3000. Now when I try to deploy another application like MeteorJS app it can not use this port. When I navigate to http://localhost:3000, i get some boilerplate template like Dance server is still running. How to fix this ?

***EDIT***

OS: ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit

Comment: How are you starting your application? Are you simply running `perl bin/app.pl` or are you using one of the other deployment methods described in [`Dancer::Deployment`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Deployment)?

Comment: And how do you stop it? `Ctrl+C`? Note that if you start it in the background with `perl bin/app.pl &`, `Ctrl+C` won't work unless you bring the process to the foreground first.

Comment: Yes wit Ctr+C. I am not expert on Perl. Just beginner :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command

```
sudo fuser 3000/tcp
```

to get the process id(s) of any process(es) using TCP port 3000, which will then allow you to use `ps`/`pstree` to inspect them or `kill` to terminate them.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I am new Ubuntu user just switched from Windows. It helped me much.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the port that Dancer uses either in the config file or [in the code](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Config).

But if you're saying that you just want to stop  the Dancer server running, then you need to kill the process.

Comment: My problem is when I quit from my Dancer app, port is still used. Like there is some process in background. Is that possible. After system restart the problem is stil there. Port is still used by Perl Dancer.